# How can I create a test starter page for Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm having a hard time finding any information on creating a basic HTML page from which I can start my Cypress tests. I want to create a simple page with a few options/buttons for running different Cypress tests I have developed. Has someone did this before or have any info about it?

The HTML I have so far is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>   
    <head>     
        <title>Cypress Runner</title>   
    </head>   
    <body>     
        <p>Test 1</p>     
        <button onclick="runner()">Run</button>     
        <script>       
            function runner() 
            {         
                // execute command "npx cypress run";       
            }     
         </script>   
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds more like web development question. Perhaps StackOverflow would be a better choice. However, I recommend asking a concrete question when you are stuck on something particular, the question now seems too general to be answered on SO. Another point of view - why do you want to do it? Cypress checks could be easily run from a console, or a pipeline, which are more common use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try also SO, but I'm not sure what specifics should I add. I need this so people without technical knowledge can run them.

Comment: Your current implementation (minimal reproducible example) and where it does not work and what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: This is the only code i wrote so far:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cypress Runner</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test 1</p>
    <button onclick="runner()">Run</button>
    <script>
      function runner() {
        // execute command "npx cypress run";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
`

Comment: Have you tried using a test site for this purpose? https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/ is often used to practice test automation.

Comment: Thank you Lee, I will use it to polish my automation skills, but now I'm looking for building a test starter.

Comment: First:  can you run `npx cypress run` from the command line? If so, then with the correct directory and run permissions you should be able to run with `exec("npx cypress run")` - see https://gist.github.com/harrypujols/2a6da11afbd9ee1bef92ddd3402a2fc4  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-javascript for more information. Note that your exact command will depend on whether you're running in a Windows or Linux environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you won't be able to execute Cypress directly from the browser using `exec` (that is, with only HTML and JS without a backend)...
- You could, however, have your page send requests to a Node backend, and have that backend run Cypress - using `exec` is a way to do that, but you can also [use Cypress as a Node module](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api), which should be cleaner.
- That said, if what you need is just a list of your tests and the ability to click to run them, that's already what the Cypress GUI does when you execute it with `npx cypress open` instead of `npx cypress run`. See [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#Opening-Cypress) for the launch options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped! Finally I decided to stick to sorry-cypress, so I can deploy my own dashboard in some cloud.